# Clear Input from Textbox after Button clicked

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have two classes. My main class is called InputClear. It's meant to hold the subcomponent and a button to clear.
The first class is called InputClear and looks like this...

```
const InputClear = () => {
    const[name2val, setName2] = useState("");
    const[min2, setMin] = useState("0...");
    const[maxval, setMax] = useState("...1000");

    const handleClick2 = () => { //This is to clear all fields of user input
        setMin("0...");
        setMax("...1000");
        console.log(min2);
    }

    return(
        <nav className={"inputclear-list"}>
            <h3 className={"inputclear-list-logo"} >
                <u>Perform Queries: </u>
            </h3>
            <UserInput name2={" Ranking "} min={min2} max={maxval}/>

            <br/>
            <button className={"button"} onClick={handleClick2}> Reset </button>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

My second class is called UserInput. It is meant to get the user input and for now do nothing with it.
This looks like this

```
[Input Box] < Ranking < [Input Box]
```

This is what I have so far...

```
const UserInput = (props) => {
    const update = (value) => {
        console.log(value.target.value);//Gets value put into text box
    }

    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='col'>
                <input type='text' placeholder={props.min} onChange={update} />
            </div>
            <div className="col">&lt;{props.name2}&lt;</div>
            <div className="col">
                <input type='text' placeholder={props.max} onChange={update} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Where I'm hitting a wall is whenever the button from InputClear is clicked, all values entered into the text boxes in UserInput are cleared.
Essentially what I mean is if it looks like this

```
[1000] < Ranking < [10000]
it then becomes
[    ] < Ranking < [     ]
```

Comment: So where are you using this `UserInput` component ? Is it placed inside `InputClear` ? Please mention where it's placed ?

Comment: We need to see the `GetInput` component, too. I can only tell that there is a closing `"` missing in the `setMax()` in `handleClick2()`.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika Sorry, I meant UserInput. I forgot to change that after copying.

Comment: @anarchist912 I had a mistype. I meant UserInput instead of GetInput, also thank you I just added that ```"```

Comment: So, you want the values to be cleared upon clicking?

Comment: Going off @KavinduVIndika's suggestion the values are being changed now, however, now whenever you try and type in  the box no characters show even though if you print the onChange they are

Comment: Can you please check the updated answer again. I just misinterpret the necessary implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `setMin` and `setMax` functions to child component to set the `state` that resides in your parent component.

```
const InputClear = () => {
    const[name2val, setName2] = useState("");
    const[min2, setMin] = useState("0...");
    const[maxval, setMax] = useState("...1000");

    const handleClick2 = () => { //This is to clear all fields of user input
        setMin("0...");
        setMax("...1000");
        console.log(min2);
    }

    return(
        <nav className={"inputclear-list"}>
            <h3 className={"inputclear-list-logo"} >
                <u>Perform Queries: </u>
            </h3>
            <UserInput name2={" Ranking "} min={min2} max={maxval} setMin={setMin} setMax={setMax} />

            <br/>
            <button className={"button"} onClick={handleClick2}> Reset </button>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

Then inside `change` function you need to update the `state` as follows, when an `onChange` event occurs on `input` fields. `placeholder` is just a temporary holder where you can put it as **minimum** and **maximum** (just strings) or you can put your initial `min` and `max` values as well.

```
const UserInput = (props) => {
    const update = (event, setValue) => {
        console.log(event.target.value); //Gets value put into text box
        setValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='col'>
                <input type='text' value={props.min} onChange={(event) => update(event, props.setMin)} />
            </div>
            <div className="col">&lt;{props.name2}&lt;</div>
            <div className="col">
                <input type='text' value={props.max} onChange={(event) => update(event, props.setMax)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I tried that as well, and that just makes the value fill up the box, not so much the grey background value of the box that is there until they start typing in it.

Comment: So you need to keep it as `readOnly` ? Without changing it anymore ? Can you check the updated answer now ?

Comment: With ```value={props.min}``` it doesn't show any character in the field except whatever props.min is. The value is being changed, but not displayed as the user is typing.

Comment: So what you're saying is you need to update these `min2` and `maxVal` when you provide any user input to the `input` field ?

Comment: Update: So that is partially what I am expecting, but it now doesn't show anything that is typed in the textbox.

Comment: Now that allows for it to be typed it, thank you!